# comparing domain accounts in two DCs - how to exclude not found messages from get-ADUser?

Tags: powershell

I'm comparing Domainaccounts between two different domains of which some have the same SamAccountName on both domains. Everything works great except that my script generates an error everytime the User is not found on the 2nd domain.

Is there a way to eliminate the output of the `Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'duda` and maybe writing a single Error via `write-host` instead?
I have also used the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` but still get the Error

Here's a snippet of my actual code for this:

```
$user_id = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase | Select-Object SamAccountName

$readthat = $user_id | Foreach-Object {
$user1 = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes
$user2 = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials -Server $dc2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($user1.SamAccountName -eq $user2.SamAccountName) {.....
```

Comment: Have you considered doing a `Try{$User1 = Get-ADUser ... -ErrorAction Stop;$Userdc1 = Get-ADUser ... -ErrorAction Stop }Catch("Account not found in at least one domain")` kind of thing?

Comment: Take a look at the `Compare-Object` command. It can tell you what is in once list or the other or in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
$user_id = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase | Select-Object SamAccountName

$readthat = $user_id | Foreach-Object {
    $user1 = Try{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes}
    catch{Write-Error "User &_ not found"}

    $user2 = try{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes -Credential $WPS_AdminCredentials -Server $dc2}
    catch{Write-Error "User &_ not found"}

    if ($user1.SamAccountName -eq $user2.SamAccountName) {.....

    }

}
```

Comment: that does the trick. thanks. 
I tried the try catch as well but not in my variables.